# Manga where time resets when the main character kills

Tags: story-identification, manga

Hi I'm looking for a manga I had lost a while ago. The main character was an esper and, whenever he killed someone, time would be reset. He tried destroying the city, and that didn't work, so he tried finding the person one by one. A green haired girl I think tries to recruit him to stop other villains.  The green haired girl has many clones or versions of herself.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: It sounds like the time reset is part of his own powers. What "person" was he looking for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *[A Useless Villain](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/a-useless-villain)*.

> High-school student Dongjin Kim seems like a typical moody teenager, but underneath it all, he’s a powerful psychic “villain” who aims to destroy humanity. But there’s a catch -- every time he uses his powers to kill, he is thrown back in time. Trapped in this time loop, Dongjin tries to narrow down the culprit by doing the one thing he knows: killing those around him. Will he be able to escape from the time loop and achieve his goal as a villain?
>
> [image]